# Expand tableview cell on button click

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cell

I did some easy trick with constraints. I made `tableView` `cell` which is expandable. On **`cell`** click it opens new cell(**black**)(Below is image for easier understanding).

My question is how can I make it work with the button which is inside the top cell which looks like **"V"**. I want it at least to rotate like 90° if `cell` is clicked. How could I achieve it.

This is how I made it to expand:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if(selectedIndex == indexPath.row){
            return 210
        }else{
            return 135
        }
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if (selectedIndex == indexPath.row){
            selectedIndex = -1
        }else{
            selectedIndex = indexPath.row
        }

        self.productstable.beginUpdates()
        self.productstable.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
        self.productstable.endUpdates()
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve using closure:

```
typealias arrowButtonTappedBlock = (button:UIButton) -> Void
```

declare a `closure` in your custom cell like below:

```
var arrowButtonTapped : arrowButtonTappedBlock!
```

and on arrow button click's action call the closure like below:

```
if arrowButtonTapped != nil {
            arrowButtonTapped(button: sender as! UIButton)
        }
```

and in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`: set the closure and perform the action you were performing in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

```
cell!.arrowButtonTapped = { (button:UIButton) -> Void in

                if (self.selectedIndex == indexPath.row){
                    self.selectedIndex = -1
                }else{
                    self.selectedIndex  = indexPath.row
                }

                self.tableview.beginUpdates()
                self.tableview.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
                self.tableview.endUpdates()
}
```

Comment: You mean inside custom cell class?

Comment: Yes. Exactly!! inside your custom cell class

Comment: Awesome. Nice logic here :) I would have thought it several days :D

Comment: @Mohammed Shakeer arrowButtonTapped  returning nil for me in swift 3

Answer (score 1):

**You can do this with easy way**

1. Delare `var selectedRowIndex = -1`
2. Create Protocol for your Custom Cell

   ```
   protocol TableViewCellDelegate {
   func BtnExpendTapped(_ cell: CustomCell) }
   ```
3. In your Custom Cell Declare protocol and add action method for button

   `var delegate: TableViewCellDelegate?`

   ```
   @IBAction func actionExpendBtnTap(_ sender: UIButton){
      delegate?.BtnExpendTapped(self)
   }
   ```
4. In your Height for Row method add your Expended and normal height as your requirement

   ```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
                   if indexPath.row == selectedRowIndex {
                       return 270 //Expanded
                   }
                   return 138.5 //Not expanded
          }
   ```
5. use your protocol delegate in view controller and add delegate method

```
func BtnExpendTapped(_ cell: CustomCell) {
     if let indexPath = tblView.indexPath(for: cell) {
         if selectedRowIndex == indexPath.row {
             selectedRowIndex = -1
         } else {
             selectedRowIndex = indexPath.row
         }
        tblView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
     }
 }
```